# Angular 9 PWA Hash mismatch (cacheBustedFetchFromNetwork)

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

i have an angular PWA and it does not start offline (http error 504). When I check out the /ngsw/state I get this error:

```
Error: Hash mismatch (cacheBustedFetchFromNetwork): https://example.com/favicon.ico: expected 566d8535a3adc2f7210a8a890bdc50ec4f91f0e3, got 8e076950c4c615772d8d5d753e07377bab9f2f27 (after cache busting)
    at PrefetchAssetGroup.&lt;anonymous&gt; (https://example.com/ngsw-worker.js:734:35)
    at Generator.next (&lt;anonymous&gt;)
    at fulfilled (https://example.com/ngsw-worker.js:174:62))
Latest manifest hash: 5952e5e67f8b4ee7115ef9d519a346712927b608
```

Using
Angular CLI: 9.1.9
Node: 12.16.1
Angular: 9.1.11

The lighthouse check on PWA gives me no errors and for redirecting the angular routes on the apache server I use .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

Anyone an idea? Thanks!

Comment: i think it is a problem with the routes, because sometimes when I open the pwa (https://example.com) in desktop browser i get a page not found, but if a I add /index.html (https://example.com/index.html) at the end, then it works ... but it is randomly

Answer (score 11):

In my case, the problem was related to the fact that I was deploying the application using git (using post-receive git hook). By default, git replaces line endings. And this led to the fact that the files on the server were different from the original ones and their hashes was also different.

I compared the hash of the file index.html on server,  it was different from the value in 'ngsw.json' file.

```
    sha1sum index.html
    04e691dbfae931bfd24513ac63d833bdfee3a1f6  index.html
```

After I disabled the line endings transformation:

```
    git config --local core.autocrlf false
```

and push project again problem disappeared and sha1sum index.html showed me the save hash as in the 'ngsw.json'.

Comment: thanks for your answer and yes the problem was that I have a sh script witch deploys the project to the server and this script also changed the icons after the ng build process. So I had to changed it that the icons get changed before the ng build script – so everything works now

Comment: thank you, that is the correct answer and should be accept